# UICollectionView Not Redrawing

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, reloaddata

I have a pretty simple UICollectionView that for some reason does not reloadData() as I would expect after a filter is applied. I am getting the right values into the filtered array, but I am getting rogue cells in the collection view that do not clear until scrolled - dequeued.

In some cases it works fine. I've yet to understand the condition in which it doesn't.

I have an array of objects master, and an array that is used to hold values that are filtered from that master array, ie:

```
hourly = hourlyMaster.filter { $0.forecastDateTime >= minDate }`
```

The cellForItemAt functionality all works fine. I just want the view to redraw after I apply the filter to the array. Apparently,

```
hourlyCollectionView.reloadData()
```

immediately following the filter is not getting it done. I'm sure there is something easy I'm missing here. ANY ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `reloadData()` in the `hourly` array's `didSet` to always reload the collection view when the data source is updated. You may be calling `reloadData()` faster than the `filter` function is executing.

```
var hourly: [Date] = [] {
     didSet {
          hourlyCollectionView.reloadData()
     }
}
```

Comment: @SGraham can you please upload more of your code so I can see how everything is laid out and what your variable declaration looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Never did get a viable solution or figure this out. Found a radar from a little while back... [here](https://openradar.appspot.com/32543861).

The workaround is simply to use yourCollectionView.reloadSections()

That solved my issue. I'm not absolutely certain if there is another variable in my circumstance that caused this issue, but nothing else worked.